# What's the difference between "Here we go" and "Here/there it is"

Tags: grammar, difference

About the difference between "Here we go" and "Here/there it is".

For example, my friend lost his wallet at my home.

I was finding his wallet, and found it on the table.

So when I found it, I said "Here we go" or "Here/there it is".

Which one is better?
Are these same meaning?

I used "Here/there it is" when the situation is like this so far.

If the stuff I was looking for was close to me, I use "Here it is".

If the stuff I was looking for was far to me, I use "There it is".

But, according to the free dictionary, "here we go" means "Said when something or someone has been found or identified".
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/here+we+go

I thought that means I can use "here we go" when I found something.
So I'm confused with the difference "Here we go" and "Here/There it is".

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

"Here we (or you) go" can be a casual/informal/slang way of saying "here is what you were looking for", or, more generally, "the current objective is achieved". "Here it is" can be used to say the same thing. I am with my friend. I say "I can't find my phone". He helps me look for it. He picks up a newspaper and, looking underneath, discovers the phone. He might say "here we go", or "here it is", or "there you are", or one of a very large number of other similar things.